# If text string contains search word from list, return defined text

Tags: excel, vba, search, find, lookup

I have a list of cells with text strings (notes) and I need to check each cell if it contains a word from the search list. Each note will only contain one of the search words. If a note contain a search word, the function need to return a Level 1 text and a Level 2 text. If a note does not contain any of the search Words, the function must return "No L1" and "No L2". 
The note can contain the search word in any part of the textstring and it can contain both letters, numbers and basic signs such as " . - , _ "

Example:

[image]

```
Notes in: A2:A7
Return of Level 1 in: B2:B7
Return of Level 2 in: C2:C7
Search words in: F2:F8
Level 1 return text in: G2:G8
Level 2 return text in: H2:H8
```

-The search words and their return text can be in other sheet...

Comment: also, Karpak answer has small bug, if word does not exist in list, it just returns first value from AA

Comment: Why in your example `CC` returns `One, Third` when those values don't appear in your source data? Same for `EE`

Answer (score 3):

In G2 Cell, you can specify the following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*"&F2&"*",A:A,0)),"")
```

and in H2 column you can specify the following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH("*"&F2&"*",A:A,0)),"")
```

After that copy these formula in below cells

If it is other way round, enter the below formula in the cell B2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(G:G,SUMPRODUCT((--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F:F,A2)))*(F:F<>""),ROW(F:F))),"")
```

and enter the below formula in C2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(H:H,SUMPRODUCT((--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F:F,A2)))*(F:F<>""),ROW(F:F))),"")
```

and now copy the formula in rest of the cells below B and C.

Comment: I think you have this backwards.  I believe the OP is looking for the formulas to go into B2 and C2.  The OP is trying to see where F is in A and return G and H.

Comment: Added the solution for the backwards as well.

Comment: can you explain each part of your equation? What is SumProduct used for? What is Index used for?

Comment: also, this answer does not work, if word does not exist in list, it just returns first value from AA

Answer (score 3):

You may benefit from SUMPRODUCT to get the row number and then output that value:

[image]

Level 1:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--((LEN($A$2:$A$7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$7,F2,"")))>0))=0,"NoL1",INDEX($B$2:$B$7,SUMPRODUCT(--((LEN($A$2:$A$7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE ($A$2:$A$7,F2,"")))>0)*ROW($A$2:$A$7))-1))
```

Level 2:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--((LEN($A$2:$A$7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$7,F2,"")))>0))=0,"NoL2",INDEX($C$2:$C$7,SUMPRODUCT(--((LEN($A$2:$A$7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE ($A$2:$A$7,F2,"")))>0)*ROW($A$2:$A$7))-1))
```

I've uploaded a sample to Gdrive so you can check the formulas:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UWfVkHUuVn88KVF9sJDvOl0fF4iQddZr/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114417674018837700466&rtpof=true&sd=true

HOW IT WORKS: The formula works based on diferent parts. First of all, because we are using SUMPRODUCT we are working on several ranges at once. By default, common functions in Excel usually require a single cell as argument, but here we are using several at once. Now how it works:

1. `(LEN($A$2:$A$7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$7,F2,"")))` will calculate the original length of the string and the new length after replacing with the search word. If there is nothing in that cell, the difference will be 0, else it will greather than cero. As example, when the search word is `AA` this part will be `{12,12,12,12,14,20}-{10,12,12,12,14,20}` and that returns array `{2,0,0,0,0,0}`. That means the **first** cell contains the search word because it's the only non zero value.
2. `--(previous formula)>0)` Now the [double unary operator](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary) will check if the previous array is greather than zero or not, returning 1 or 0, so `{2,0,0,0,0,0}` now is `{1,0,0,0,0,0}`
3. Steps 1 and 2 are wrapped inside a SUMPRODUCT that will summarize everything in the previous array, so `SUMPRODUCT({1,0,0,0,0,0}) = 1+0+0+0+0+0 = 1`.
4. All previous steps are wrapped inside an IF Function. If the previous result is equal to 0 then return `NoL1` because there is no match, else keep calculating.
5. Now the formula repeats again steps 1 and 2 and gets again an array like this: `{1,0,0,0,0,0}`.
6. Notice now there is an additional calculation in this second SUMPRODUCT because we have added `ROW($A$2:$A$7)`. This will create an array of all row numbers, and the output is `{2,3,4,5,6,7}`.
7. Using the asterisk `*` will multiply the array from step 5 by the array from step 6 like this: `{1,0,0,0,0,0} * {2,3,4,5,6,7} = {2,0,0,0,0,0}` and this is critical because the only number returned here is the **row number** that holds the note with the searched word inside!!!.
8. Once again, step 7 is inside SUMPRODUCT so it will sum up all values and the output is `2`
9. the output of step 8 is the second argument in the INDEX function to return the desired note. Notice we do `-1` because ROW returns the real row number relative to whole worksheet but because your first row of data is row 2 and not row 1, we must do `-1` to adjust.
10. Finally everything gets into a simple INDEX like this: `INDEX($C$2:$C$7,2-1)` and this return the expected output.

Formula for Level 2 is exactly the same but changing just where to extract data in the INDEX part and returninf `NoL2` is there is no match.

I strongly suggest you to use the tool **Evaluate Formula** so you can see step by step how Excel makes each calculation. You will understand much better.

> [Evaluate a nested formula one step at a
> time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7)

More reputable sources you must read and understand:

> > [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)
>
> > [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
>
> > [ROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d)
>
> > [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)
>
> > [LEN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/len-function-038f2e0d-57d3-4f35-ae74-9a79d66e8fc2)
>
> > [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)

Comment: the point of the question is to clarify what Kapark did, or can you break down/explain each part of your equation?thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Except Excel formulas, Excel VBA UDF could be used here probably.
>
> > *This solution is a suggestion for those who want/need/can use own VBA code.*

```
Option Explicit
' Option Compare Text ' That is, "AAA" is equal to "aaa".
' Option Compare Binary ' That is, "AAA" is less than "aaa".

Public Function SearchNotes( _
    note As Range, _
    criteria As Range, _
    no1 As String, _
    no2 As String)
    
    On Error GoTo err_search

    Dim k As Variant
    Dim d As Object
    
    Set d = Map(criteria)
    
    For Each k In d.Keys()
        If Contains(note, k) Then
            SearchNotes = Array(d(k).Cells(2).Value, d(k).Cells(3).Value)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    SearchNotes = Array(no1, no2)
    
    Exit Function
    
err_search:
    ' Debug.Print "Error occured: '" & Err.Description & "'. Error number: '" & Err.Number & "'.", vbCritical, "Error"
    SearchNotes = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function

Private Function Contains(note As Range, k As Variant) As Boolean
    Contains = IIf(VBA.Strings.InStr(VBA.CStr(note.Value), VBA.CStr(k)) > 0, _
        True, _
        False)
End Function

Private Function Map(criteria As Range) As Object
    Dim d As Object
    Dim r As Range
    Dim k As String
    
    Set d = VBA.Interaction.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    For Each r In criteria.Rows
        k = r.Cells(1).Value
        If Not d.Exists(k) Then
            d.Add Key:=k, Item:=r
        End If
    Next
    Set Map = d
End Function
```

> How to call this UDF from Excel
>
> > **Important**: select two cells as the formula will return an array of two values

[image]

> Hit `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` as the UDF must be used as Array-Formula

[image]

> Finally simply copy the formula in cells B2:C2 to the other rows

[image]