# How to MATCH text with a wildcard in the target matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to assign a transaction type to a list of credit card transactions. The type depends on the description of each transaction, which is a text value. I use `INDEX` `MATCH` to lookup the type in a description index table which maps from transaction descriptions to types.

Here is the problem: I want to avoid a long list of very similar entries in the description index table. I already have more than ten entries that contain the substring "amazon". Therefore, I thought about using wildcards in the `MATCH` so that all transactions that contain the substring "amazon" (or similar) are mapped to the same type. Unfortunately, `MATCH` supports wildcards only in the search value, not in the target matrix. Therefore it seems to be impossible to maintain a description index table that uses wildcard matching patterns.

Can this be done?

Consider the following sample tables. I want to match `Description` against `Pattern` to find the `Type`.

**Transaction Table**

```
| Description       | Amount |
|-------------------|--------|
|Amazon Merchant XY | 100.00 |
|Amazon online //>  |  89.99 |
|Amazon.com         |  32.64 |
```

**Lookup Table**

```
| Pattern   | Type         |
|-----------|--------------|
|*amazon*   |Shoping       |
|*itunes*   |Entertainment |
```

Comment: could you show the layout?

Comment: This looks like the similar issue mentioned in the following post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351338/if-text-string-contains-search-word-from-list-return-defined-text/39352347#39352347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution for you:

```
=INDEX($F$2:$F$3,MAX(ROW($A$1:$A$2)*IF(ISERROR(FIND($E$2:$E$3,A2)),0,1)))
```

This needs to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It works with the following setup:
[image]

---

### **Explanation**

```
IF(ISERROR(FIND($E$2:$E$3,A2)),0,1)
```

Loops through your lookup table and creates an array of ones and zeros depending on whether the lookup value was found in the string **A2** in the case of **A2** the array would be `{1,0}`

Multiplying this string by `ROW($A$1:$A$2)` effectively gives you the row position that you can use with the `INDEX` function:
`{1,0}*{1,2} = {1,0}` not that in the case of **A4** we would have something like this: `{0,1}*{1,2} = {0,2}`

So taking the `MAX` of this gives you the number **1** or **2** depending on which string was found and you can use that as normal with a `INDEX` function. Note that using the `MAX` function means that if you have more than one match it will take the lowest match in the list.

Comment: Nice explanation *(+1)*

Comment: I prefer the `MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$2:$E$3,A2)),0)` method as the second argument in the INDEX(). then wrap the whole in IFERROR.  Also your formula will return the  both cells in an array if none match as the max will return `0`.  With MATCH it will return an error if no match is found that can be manipulated to say such.  Yours has the potential of false positives.