# Excel Partial Match on Another Column and Categorize

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I check if one word in a column contains keyword in another column, and then categorize using Excel?

I am trying to categorize my credit card statement.

1. First Excel sheet has transaction list of all the stores, vendors, with extra keywords.
2. Second Excel Sheet has keywords and their categories.

Trying to use Vlookup, partial matches, not sure. There could be 200 transactions in a credit card statement each month, and 50 categories lookup.

Resource below.

**Excel Sheet 1:**

| Credit Card Description | Amount | Category (trying to fill in) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Store Amazon | 25 | Equipment |
| Vendor McDonalds TX | 4 | Food |
| Maple Doctor Office | 47 | Medicine |
| Emerald Bakery | 9 | Food |

**Excel Sheet 2:**

| Vendor | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Amazon | Equipment |
| McDonalds | Food |
| Doctor | Medical |
| Bakery | Food |

Resources:

https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/vlookup-contains-partial-match/

Comment: So the answer would be in the partial match lookup in your resources link. What have you tried? What's not working?

Comment: the resource is something different, it wasn't working, I just started learning excel last week cc @P.b

Comment: So what's your try, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `FILTER()` function with `COUNTIFS()`.

```
=@FILTER($H$2:$H$5,COUNTIFS(A2,"*"& $G$2:$G$5 & "*"))
```

To fill down result automatically can use `MAP()` or `BYROW()`. Try-

```
=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,FILTER(H2:H5,COUNTIFS(x,"*"& G2:G5 & "*"))))
```

[image]

For Excel 2016:

```
=LOOKUP(,-FIND(" "&Sheet2!$A$2:$A$10&" "," "&A2&" "),Sheet2!$B$2:$B$10)

=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$5)/(COUNTIFS(A2,"*"& $G$2:$G$5 & "*")),ROW($1:$1))),"")
```

Comment: @mattsmith5 Can you try this as array formula for Excel-2016. `=IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$5)/(COUNTIFS(A2,"*"& $G$2:$G$5 & "*")),ROW($1:$1))),"")`

Comment: Aggregate shouldn't require array entry. Try as normal formula.

Comment: With `SUMPRODUCT()` formula would be `=INDEX($H$2:$H$5,SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A2,"*"& $G$2:$G$5 & "*")*(ROW($H$2:$H$5)-ROW($H$1))))`.

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($H$2:$H$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$5)/(COUNTIFS(A2,"*"& $G$2:$G$5 & "*")),ROW($1:$1))),"") this one is better, as it returns null empty space if not found

Comment: feel free to leave this answer this the other question also, I can send bounty https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351338/if-text-string-contains-search-word-from-list-return-defined-text

Comment: @mattsmith5 If this answer helps then please consider accepting the answer. I will check that question as well.